# Setting subscription dates in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, date, timestamp

I'm dealing with a website where people can subscribe to certain things for virtual money. I need to put the dates at which subscriptions end in the database. My table has a field "expiration" for that, which is a DATE.

When the user extends his subscription, I need to add 1 month to this date. However, if the subscription has already expired, I want to set "expiration" to 1 month from now, not to 1 month from when the subscription expired.

I've tried:

```
UPDATE shop_user_rights SET expiration = ADDDATE(MAX(expiration, CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

and

```
UPDATE shop_user_rights SET expiration = FROM_UNIXTIME(
 MIN(
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expiration),
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
 )
),
expiration = ADDDATE(expiration, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

But both give syntax errors. Is there a way to do this in 1 query, or do I have to use some SELECT queries beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) functions are for grouping: you want [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) instead.